# Search multiple fields and output summed score with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple fields, eg. `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, that I want to search a single term against each and return the aggregated score where any field matches. I do not want to search each field by the same terms, only search a field by its own term, eg. `f1:t1`, `f2:t2`, `f3:t3`.

Originally, I was using a `must` bool query with `multi_match` and the fields all concatenated as `t1 t2 t3` and all fields searched, but the results aren't great. Using a `dis_max` query gets better results where I'm able to search the individual fields by their own term, but if for example `t1` is found in `f1` AND `t2` in `f2` the results from `dis_max` give back the highest resulting score. So if I have 3 documents with `{ "f1": "foo", "f2": "foo" }`, `{ "f1": "foo", "f2": "bar" }`, `{ "f1": "foo", "f2": "baz" }` and I search for `f1:foo` and `f2:ba` I can still get back the first record with `f2` of `foo` in the case where it was created most recently. What I'm trying to do is say that `f1` matched `foo` so there's a score related to that, and `f2` matched `bar` so the resultant score should be `f1.score + f2.score` always bringing it up to the top because it matches both.

I'm finding that I could programmatically build a query that uses `query_string`, eg. (limiting to two fields for brevity)

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(f1:foo OR f1.autocomplete:foo) OR (f2:ba OR f2.autocomplete:ba)"
    }
  }
}
```

but I need to add a boost to the fields and this doesn't allow for that. I could also use a `dis_max` with a set of `queries`, but I'm really not sure how to aggregate score in that case.

Using better words, what I'm trying to search for is: if I have people data and I want to search for first name and last name, without searching first by last and last by first, a result that matches both first and last name should be higher than if it only returns one or the other.

Is there a better/good/proper way to achieve this using something? I feel like I've been over a lot of the query API and haven't found something that would be most good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple should query

```
 minimum_should_match:1,
 "should" : [
        { "term" : { "f1" : "foo" } },
        { "term" : { "f2" : "ba" } }
      ]
```

more clause a document matches , more score it will have.

Comment: This improves the scoring, but it only matches records that have both `foo` as `f1` and `ba` as `f2`, I need to also match those which have only `foo` as `f1` or `ba` as `f2`.

Comment: @geoffjay should clause is like "OR" . It will return a document even if only one of the condition matches

Comment: the query I was using wasn't including the `autocomplete` index, adding those in and making some minor changes got me where I need to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to edit the answer provided so posting the solution that was derived from the other answer here.

```json
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "f1": {
              "query": "foo",
              "boost": 1.5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "f1.autocomplete": {
              "query": "foo",
              "boost": 1.5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "f2": {
              "query": "ba",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "f2.autocomplete": {
              "query": "ba",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This gets me results that meet all of my criteria.